# Max value in range for each row in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to get max value for each row of column in specific range in Pandas,
for example I would like to get max value from 4 last values in column `A` for each row

```
|    | A  | Max_Range |
|----|----|-----------|
| 0  | 10 | NaN       |
| 1  | 12 | NaN       |
| 2  | 14 | NaN       |
| 3  | 8  | 14        | #<-- (Range 0:3)
| 4  | 9  | 14        | #<-- (Range 1:4)
| 5  | 10 | 14        | #<-- (Range 2:5)
| 6  | 15 | 15        | #<-- (Range 3:6)
| 7  | 15 | 15        | #<-- (Range 4:7)
| 8  | 16 | 16        | #<-- (Range 5:8)
| 9  | 10 | 16        | #<-- (Range 6:9)
| 10 | 11 | 16        | #<-- (Range 7:10)
| 11 | 12 | 12        | #<-- (Range 8:11)
| 12 | 13 | 13        | #<-- (Range 9:12)
| 13 | 14 | 14        | #<-- (Range 10:13)
| 14 | 20 | 20        | #<-- (Range 11:14)
| 15 | 19 | 20        | #<-- (Range 12:15)
```

Comment: This is simple rolling: `df["A"].rolling(window=4).max()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df['max_range'] = df['A'].rolling(4).max()
```

Output:

```
     A    max_range
0   10          NaN
1   12          NaN
2   14          NaN
3    8         14.0
4    9         14.0
5   10         14.0
6   15         15.0
7   15         15.0
8   16         16.0
9   16         16.0
10  16         16.0
11  12         16.0
12  13         16.0
13  14         16.0
14  20         20.0
15  20         20.0
```